# C# - Object without '= new Kid()'

Tags: c#, .net, class, object, reference

Goodmorning.

How is it possible at the line 28 and 29 the kd has the ability to use the property and the function without using 'Kid kd = new Kid();' at the line 24.

Normally i get the error at the line 8, it wants 'Kid kd = new Kid();'

thnx!

[image: 1]

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public class Toy
    {
        Kid kd;//property
        
        public Toy ()//constructor
        {
            kd.nameKid = "gianestras";
            kd.MyToys();
        }
    }       
    
    public class Kid
    {   
        public string nameKid = "";//property
        
        public Kid () {}//constructor
        
        public void MyToys()//function
        {
        }
    }
    
    
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        Kid kd;
        kd.MyToys();    
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Only if you make the class static

Comment: It's unclear what you asking ... but I assume that why in Toy constructo it's  allowed and in Main not? ... well field may be initialized before method call in Main it is obvious that kd is not initialized

Comment: Line 28 will/would throw an exception in runtime, but the compiler cannot possibly _infer_ it. In `Main` it _can_.

Comment: Maybe only converting to a struct. classes are reference type, does not have a standart value, it's null until you create a instance of it It's not like C++ you can declare a class as value or reference (pointer). Structs in the other hands are value types, that can have a default value, but you lose inheritance capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler (at least that one) just cannot know that it is impossible for *kd* to ever get a valid instance. That is simply a limitation. If you had not written line 28 inside the constructor but another method, it would be perfectly valid that *kd* might be assigned outside at some point.
The error checker is nice, but not an absolute guarantee that there are no runtime errors.